# Why mysql innodb table - auto increment column jumps by more that 1 number even if the variables like 'auto_increment_increment' are set as 1?

Tags: mysql, sql

Why mysql innodb table - auto increment column jumps by more that 1 number even if the variables like 'auto_increment_increment' are set as 1 ?.

Note : no update or delete query is used on the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Auto_increment value is incremented at INSERT queries too. The trick is that it can be incremented even if no real rows be added. There are several cases and I'll explain them using small demo table:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  UNIQUE KEY (name)
) ENGINE = INNODB;

root@localhost/test> Show table status like 'test'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           Name: test
         Engine: InnoDB
        Version: 10
     Row_format: Compact
           Rows: 0
 Avg_row_length: 0
    Data_length: 16384
Max_data_length: 0
   Index_length: 16384
      Data_free: 0
 Auto_increment: 1 <-- Next auto_increment field value
    Create_time: 2016-06-06 14:39:48
    Update_time: NULL
     Check_time: NULL
      Collation: utf8_general_ci
       Checksum: NULL
 Create_options:
        Comment:
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Case #1: INSERT IGNORE

```
root@localhost/test> INSERT IGNORE INTO test (name) VALUES ("One");
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

root@localhost/test> INSERT IGNORE INTO test (name) VALUES ("One");
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

root@localhost/test> SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY id;
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | One  |
+----+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

root@localhost/test> Show table status like 'test'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           Name: test
         Engine: InnoDB
        Version: 10
     Row_format: Compact
           Rows: 1
 Avg_row_length: 16384
    Data_length: 16384
Max_data_length: 0
   Index_length: 16384
      Data_free: 0
 Auto_increment: 3
    Create_time: 2016-06-06 14:39:48
    Update_time: NULL
     Check_time: NULL
      Collation: utf8_general_ci
       Checksum: NULL
 Create_options:
        Comment:
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Case #2: INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

```
root@localhost/test> INSERT INTO test (name) VALUES ("One") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name=VALUES(name);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

root@localhost/test> SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY id;
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | One  |
+----+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

root@localhost/test> INSERT INTO test (name) VALUES ("One") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name=VALUES(name);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

root@localhost/test> Show table status like 'test'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           Name: test
         Engine: InnoDB
        Version: 10
     Row_format: Compact
           Rows: 1
 Avg_row_length: 16384
    Data_length: 16384
Max_data_length: 0
   Index_length: 16384
      Data_free: 0
 Auto_increment: 5
    Create_time: 2016-06-06 14:39:48
    Update_time: NULL
     Check_time: NULL
      Collation: utf8_general_ci
       Checksum: NULL
 Create_options:
        Comment:
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Case #3: INSERT with errors

```
root@localhost/test> INSERT INTO test (name) VALUES ("One");
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'One' for key 'name'

root@localhost/test> Show table status like 'test'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           Name: test
         Engine: InnoDB
        Version: 10
     Row_format: Compact
           Rows: 1
 Avg_row_length: 16384
    Data_length: 16384
Max_data_length: 0
   Index_length: 16384
      Data_free: 0
 Auto_increment: 6
    Create_time: 2016-06-06 14:39:48
    Update_time: NULL
     Check_time: NULL
      Collation: utf8_general_ci
       Checksum: NULL
 Create_options:
        Comment:
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

You can read more about the reasons why these holes are occurred at this article: https://www.percona.com/blog/2011/11/29/avoiding-auto-increment-holes-on-innodb-with-insert-ignore/ or MySQL documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html#innodb-auto-increment-lock-modes

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html         Here its mentioned types of auto increment.   changing them to one of them will be help or will it result in performance decrease ?

Comment: As far as I can see, “traditional” lock mode (innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 0) can help to avoid holes inside the id sequence, but this mode can cause some performance problems because it acquires table level lock on each INSERT statement and blocks concurrent inserts. All other lock modes can create the holes.

Answer (score 0):

Rolling back transactions that would insert rows will make the auto increment counter skip values.

Answer (score 0):

Also INSERT IGNORE and INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY will grow auto increment counter.